# JQuery fading in fading out continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Currently the editor that I am using is Adobe Dreamweaver. In my editor the following 
statements work during trial, however in my browsers such as Safari, Mozilla, and Chrome my fade in and fade out is not working at all. I'd like for them to constantly fade out then fade back in, but the images still remain visible. Any incites as to why this is happening to me?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x=0;
    while(x==0 ){
        $("#Imag1").fadeOut(3000);
    $("#Imag2").fadeOut(8000);
        $("#Imag3").fadeOut(6000); 
        x++;

    if(x==1){
        $("#Imag1").fadeIn(2000);
            $("#Imag2").fadeIn(5000);
            $("#Imag3").fadeIn(9000);
        x--;
        } 
    }
});
```

Comment: You are mission a `)` closing paran and `;` semicolon in your code example..just a copy/paste error or is that your actual code? If so, you need to add those in order for your javascript to run correctly.

Comment: With the change @Alex mentioned, this code looks like it just goes into a hard loop, x swaps between 0 and 1, both the while loop condition and the fadein condition will always be true.

Comment: @Alex, that was a copy and past issue.

Comment: @dc5, I have tried to make the conditions true or false and it yet has worked out.

Comment: You call fadeOut then fadeIn... This means that it will immediately be faded out then back in on document.ready... Is that the effect you want?

Comment: @Zeaklous, Yes that is the effect that i want on my images. However,it will not work with my browsers.

Comment: And there is no need for a while loop at all. In general they are bad practice because of endless loops and

Comment: @Zeaklous,the only way for this to work infinitely is for me to use the while loop.Do you have any other advice that you can point me to.

Comment: OH, that's what the problem is. Let me update my answer

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nEQF7/2/

Answer (score 7):

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/m7HcT/1/
It creates a re-useable method for you to call on any element you want to flash.

HTML:

```
<div class='block' id='Imag1'></div>
<div class='block' id='Imag2'></div>
<div class='block' id='Imag3'></div>
```

jQuery:

```
fadeloop('#Imag1',1500,1200,true);
fadeloop('#Imag2',100,200,true);
fadeloop('#Imag3',3000,7000,true);

//The element is cached inside the function so we don't make 
//Multiple DOM calls on elements we have already found.
//Each Interval is completely independant

function fadeloop(el,timeout,timein,loop){
    var $el = $(el),intId,fn = function(){
         $el.fadeOut(timeout).fadeIn(timein);
    };
    fn();
    if(loop){
        intId = setInterval(fn,timeout+timein+100);
        return intId;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: ,your approach works on adobe editor;however, it does not work on komodoedit,safari, mozilla,or chrome. something must be wrong with my browsers.

Comment: Could you please explain this code?  It works perfectly, but when I try to use "$('#Imag1').finish();" to stop the animation it doesn't work.  How would one toggle this fading behavior on and off to conserve system resources when the element is hidden?

Comment: The interval id is returned.  You need to cache that id if you plan to clear it later.  Here is an example. http://jsfiddle.net/m7HcT/4/

Comment: Works as expected

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the while loop and it works perfectly

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Imag1").fadeOut(3000);
    $("#Imag2").fadeOut(8000);
    $("#Imag3").fadeOut(6000);
    $("#Imag1").fadeIn(2000);
    $("#Imag2").fadeIn(5000);
    $("#Imag3").fadeIn(9000);
});
```

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6BXJu/1/)

**EDIT**

Since you want it endless, you can put the effects into another function and run it on the callback. [Updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6BXJu/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    fadeThem();
});
function fadeThem() {
    $("#Imag1").fadeOut(3000, function() {
        $(this).fadeIn(2000, fadeThem());
    // Apply the callback to the one with the shortest combined animation time
    });
    $("#Imag2").fadeOut(8000, function() {
        $(this).fadeIn(5000);
    });
    $("#Imag3").fadeOut(6000, function() {
        $(this).fadeIn(9000);
    });
}
```

Comment: Then it is something on your end, not mine

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem. All this time the link element was missing its less than sign(>). So frustrated after 4 hours, I found my mistake.